# change color of the face in a 2D ConvexHullMesh

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, mesh

If I say

```
tri = ConvexHullMesh[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]
```

a triangle is rendered in blue.  How can I change that color?  An answer to an earlier question suggested passing `tri`, which is actually a `BoundaryMeshRegion`, to `HighlightMesh`, like this:

```
hm = HighlightMesh[tri, {Style[0, PointSize[0.05], Red], 
                         Style[1, Thick, Black],
                         Style[2, Green]}]
```

That does indeed highlight the vertices as red dots and the edges as black lines; but the triangle is still blue.  The `Properties` list in `InputForm[hm]` sets the `MeshCellStyle` of the 2-dimensional cells to green.  But perhaps `HighlightMesh` is not prepared to highlight the top-dimensional face?

Maybe I should be using some different approach?

Comment: Your code gives me a green triangle. Win10 V10.3.1

Comment: Aha.  My blue triangle comes from Version 10.0.2.0.  So maybe this was a bug that has been fixed?

Comment: Most probably, can't test that, don't have 10.0 :/

Comment: This was a bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2.  For people still running 10.0, an easy fix is described in a Stack Exchange posting from 2014 that you can find by searching for "ConvexHullMesh Bug 2D"..

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this example could be helpful:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
ch = VoronoiMesh[pts]; mp = MeshPrimitives[ch, 2];
ml = MeshPrimitives[ch, 1];
mpt = MeshPrimitives[ch, 0];
Graphics[Riffle[RandomColor[Length@mp], mp]~Join~{Red, Thick, ##} & @@
     ml~Join~{Blue, PointSize[0.02], ##} & @@ mpt]
```

[image]